# How to carry a variable over to another class/window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a basic login screen that uses an ID to login (e.g 1122333) and upon successful login, it closes the login window and opens a new window which will show information depending on who logged in (using the ID 1122333). I am trying to store the ID from the login as a parameter in the main window but am having no luck.

Am I approaching this wrong? Is there another way to variables across the whole solution?

I open the window with `MainWindow main = new Mainwindow(StudentId)`
I then try to use `StudentId` in the main window as part of a Sql Statement but no data comes from the statement. It works if I hard code an ID in though.

```
//Login Window

private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string StudentId = tbxStudentId.Text;
    MainWindow main = new MainWindow(StudentId);
    this.Close();
    main.ShowDialog();
}
...

//Main Window
public MainWindow(string StudentId)
{ 
    Datamanager dm = new Datamanager();
    sqlquery = "Select * from Enrollments Where (Student_Id= @Id And Result= 'Current')";
    SqlCommand cmd = dm.RunQuery(sqlquery);

    SqlParameter Id = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.VarChar);

    Id.Value = StudentId;
}
```

The query returns no data unless I hardcode the ID (Id.value = "1122333") and then it works as expected. I checked to see if the parameter carries any value by trying to make a labels text equal to it, but as far as I can tell there is nothing being fed into the parameter.

Comment: Use the debugger to check what value is in the parameter once you step into the constructor. It should be the same as the text in the textbox. Also from your question it looks like the value you hardcoded was of type int while the value you're actually passing in is a string. Are you sure that you can use a string there or should you maybe convert the string to an int first?

Comment: What is a DataManager Class and how are doing RunQuery from that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is not related to the parameter passed to the window, but rather to the way your are using it:

```
// Using a value:
SqlCommand cmd = dm.RunQuery(sqlquery);

// ...then defining it afterward:
SqlParameter Id = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.VarChar);
Id.Value = StudentId;
```

Switch this around, add the value, and then try again:

```
// Define it as a new SqlParameter first...
SqlParameter Id = new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.VarChar);
Id.Value = StudentId;

// ...and only then, add it:
cmd.Parameters.Add(Id);
SqlCommand cmd = dm.RunQuery(sqlquery);
```

Comment: Thank you this helped. Only change I needed to do was to move one line above another:
    SqlCommand cmd = dm.RunQuery(sqlquery);
    //and then this line
    cmd.Parameters.Add(Id);

Comment: @taydoubleyou Glad to help, good to hear that my answer was useful.

Answer (score -1):

You should add parameters and value of that parameter then "runQuery".

Comment: This will not work, because you are using cmd before you declare it.

Comment: @SQLGeorge, I try to say set parameter's value first then run the query. Maybe it could be problem.